# Firebase Not Running Callbacks As Expected

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase DB with a `{ hello: 'world'}` at its root. Whenever I try to read `hello`'s value in Node, the callback isn't executed unless I modify the value from within the Node process.

Here's the `once` call:

```
let callback = (snapshot) => {
  console.log('The value is ', snapshot.val());
};

db.ref('hello').once('value', callback);
```

At this point I'd expect the callback to run and print "The value is world" printed... but nothing happens. Now say I use `on` instead of `once`. Even if I modify the value from the Firebase web console or another Node process, the callback still isn't called! The strange thing is all of this code works as expected in a browser with the same library version (v3.0.2).

The only way I've managed to execute the callback is by modifying the value directly from the same Node process.

```
db.ref('hello').once('value', callback);
db.ref('test').set('moon');

// => 'The value is moon.'
```

I've created a [repository](https://github.com/fny/firebase-callback-issues) with test scripts to help replicate an debug the issue.

Comment: Is your node processing exiting? Are you sure it is still running at the time the callback should be happening?

Comment: Yes the Node process is still running.

Comment: Try adding an error callback and seeing what error it logs.

Comment: @Kato The error callback is never called.

Comment: I believe nothing without code to run.

Comment: @Kato See the repository link I posted. Also this bug has been verified by Firebase staff.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a known issue affecting certain accounts, and the Firebase team is working on it!

Comment: Do you know if there is a public tracker where we can watch the bug?  Been pulling my hair out on this one...

Comment: There's no public bug tracker, but if you email support, they'll put you on a list to get notified when this changes.